# Assets Library Framework on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is there any possibilities to use Assets Library Framework on iPad? As I know it is a framework of IOS4 and higher, but I need to use it in my iPad application.

Answer (score 3):

No, you'll have to code for iOS4.2 on iPad, coming this year.  You should be able to install it on a test device.

Comment: Apple have said it'll release in November, so not long to go.

Comment: @JosephH Not everyone will upgrade as soon as it's released, though.

Comment: @Emil Very true - but given it adds multitasking, game center, folders and printing (amongst other things) I'd imagine most folks (especially the ones likely to spend money on apps) will be upgrading sooner rather than later.

Comment: @JosepH That's also very true, but to support all devices, I would recommend you don't use functions for 4.2 yet, at least until 2011.